# PHP arbitrary precision with dec/hex conversion

Tags: php, math, arbitrary-precision

I need to do arbitrary precision math in PHP.

But the `bcmath` implementation doesn't seem to have ways to convert between decimal and binary/hex.

I need to take an arbitrary precision number WITH RADIX in either decimal or hex, then output in either decimal or hex.

I need arbitrary precision on both sides of the radix in both bases and in the conversion between bases.

I need to put in on a web host, so I probably don't have access to using system commands.

The only thing I can think of right now is my own PHP implementation of arbitrary precision `dechex` and `hexdec`. Arbitrary precision on the right side of the radix could be a bit "extra loopy". Then I could just use `bcmath` for the actual calculation and flip bases as needed with my own PHP functions.

Is there a better way? am I missing something?

Edit..

So I found a solution.
Use 1024 for each 10 binary digits or 3 decimal digits to shift the radix until I have enough precision on the integer side.. then shift it back

I can shift binary radix without division operations, and I can use bcdiv on the decimal side

10.01 decimal

Multiply by 1024 (2^10)

Conversation to binary as int

Right 10 bits become fractional part

Or

1.FFFF hex

Convert to binary

Shift 20 bits (increments of 10, enough to put the precision required on the int side of radix)

Convert hex int to decimal

Divide decimal by 2^20

Comment: what does "radix" mean to you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A radix is what goes between the integer and fractional component... in base 10 it's called a decimal point

Comment: I think Community bot and President James K. Polk are right, could you provide some more info on why you need numbers that can be converted or better explain the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

To work with arbitrary precision numbers you could use [Brick\Math](https://github.com/brick/math).
To convert between decimal or hex you could use [phpsec](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php).

Both libraries offer a part of functionality you require.

Comment: Php sec seems to only handle integers.. I need radix as well.. I need to convert arbitrary precision fractions as well

Comment: you will probably need to write part of that solution yourself. One thing that comes to mind is that you could multiply BigDecimal with appropriate number of zeros to get integer and than convert between bases and divide again